# AngujarJS: how to format number when conditional is used inside brackets {{ var | number:2 }}?

Tags: angularjs

I know formatting a number can be done by:

```
{{-val | number:4}}
```

How can I format to a number when ternary operator is used inside of brackets like this:

```
{{ rC.eD.isPaid ? '| $' + rC.eD.Price : ''}}
```

This is what I tried but it is NOT working:

```
{{ rC.eD.isPaid ? '| $' + rC.eD.Price : '' | number:4}}
```

Ideas?
TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put brackets in the right place:

```
$scope.val = true;
$scope.number = 100;
...

{{val ? (number | number: 2) : number}} //outputs 100.00

{{!val ? (number | number: 2) : number}} //outputs 100

{{val ? '$' + (number | number: 2) : number}} //outputs $100.00
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62vaLqqq/

Comment: someone give gold to @yBrodsky :D